# How do I know I am squatting properly?

Tags: squats, gym, exercise-technique, legs, form

I've had a long layoff from the gym due to health reasons but am finally able to get back into it now.

Recently I've been doing some backsquats (for the first time in years)... I noticed I was getting some slight pain in one of my knees.

It wasn't until I was able to find a different squat rack, one with a mirror, where I realised I was sorta leaning more to one side when squatting, and basically putting most of my weight on the side that was starting to hurt.

So it got me thinking... if I have no mirror, and no gym buddy, how can I avoid these things happening in future?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of an uneven squat is a muscular imbalance, meaning for whatever reason one of your legs may be stronger/weaker than the other. You could test this by simply doing a unilateral exercise such as single leg split squats or a single leg RDL and seeing if one side can perform more reps or lift more weight and therfore is stronger. Keep using these unilateral exercises to correct the imbalance as traing each side independently means that neither one side can end up taking more of the load than other and therfore works each side equally. Of course for this to correct the imbalance you must, once identified, do the weaker side first and match the load and volume to the weaker side. E.g. if your left leg is weaker, do the split squats on the left leg first. If you used 10kg dumbells and managed 8 reps, then make sure to use the same 10kg dumbells on the right, and again only do 10 reps, even if you feel you could do more.